# Javascript objects - feature missing from overall object, yet exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, properties, mongoose

Strange problem here. I'm running Node/Express/Mongoose/Leaflet. I pull an array of locations from my db, and once the callback is initiated, I iterate over those locations to find a bunch of string passages that deals with each location. I then try to append the array of passages to each location object, and then append the locations array to a GeoJSON FeatureCollection.

```
Location.find({}, { _id: 0 }, function (err, locations) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('DB Error loading all locations');
    res.redirect('/');
} else {
    var num = 0;
    console.log("Beginning finding all passages");
    locations.forEach(function (location) {
    num++;
    console.log("Looking up a location");
    Passage.find({"placekey": location.properties.placekey}, function (err, passages) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('DB Error finding passage for: ' + location.properties.placekey);
        } else {
            console.log("Passage was found!");
            location.properties.passages = passages[0]; //take first passage
            num--;
        }
        if (num === 0) {
            console.log("All passages were found!");
            var featureCollection = {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": locations
            };
            console.log(featureCollection);
            console.log(featureCollection.features[0].properties);
            console.log(featureCollection.features[0].properties.passages);
            res.json(featureCollection);
            console.log("JSON sent over!");
        }
    });
});
```

Logging the featureCollection gets me my featureCollection without any passages:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "num_books": 62,
        "Age": "Built 1078",
        "ID": "",
        "num_mentions": 325,
        "Place": "The Tower",
        "placekey": "TheTower",
        "GeocodeNotes": "",
        "Notes": "Built on the site of Roman fortifications, the central part of the Tower, known as the White Tower, was built in 1078 by William the Conqueror. Subsequent rings of fortification were added later. It was used as a royal residence as well as a prison and place of execution until Elizabethan times. England's child king, Edward V, and his brother were murdered in the Tower in 1483 supposedly by their uncle, Richard III.",
        "Class": "n/a",
        "Type": "Landmark"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.076111,
          51.508056
        ]
      }
    },
   // more objects
```

No passages property.

However, when I use console.log(featureCollection.features[0].properties.passages), I get the first passage:

```
 {
  "_id": "51deebdbb2b5de1b8b6d7da1",
  "index": 27100,
  "bookid": 1,
  "author": "Ainsworth, William",
  "place": "The Tower",
  "placekey": "TheTower",
  "query_ok": true,
  "year": 1839,
  "corpus": "Chadwyck",
  "fn": "/Volumes/LilaData1/Plain2/Chadwyck/lilaBookId_00149.txt",
  "context_a": "The course of the carpenter's meditations was here...
  //more features
}
```

Moreover, using (if 'passages' in featureCollection.features[0].properties) gives me true. In fact, I can condition sending a JSON response from the server to that, and my featureCollection without passages will be sent...

Sorry for the long-winded post, but I'm really going crazy over this. Any ideas?

Thank you! :)

Comment: I tried to reproduce this both in browser and node, but with no luck. Maybe it'd be easier to figure this out if you could provide some example that we can run -- reducing your code step by step such that it still produces the problem. It sure does seem odd.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the inspect defined on Document  is interfering with console.log operation. This inspect does not consider the properties added to the document instance (like documentinst.prop=1).

To fix your problem try to use toJSON on the return documents and then attach properties to the return object

In your case,

```
var _locations = [];

locations.forEach(function(_location){ // actual mongoose document

  var location;

  location = _location.toJSON(); // do toJSON on the _location mongoose document

  _locations.push(location); //push this object into the new array _locations

  ....logic for passages...

  //imp - add properties to the location object return from toJSON

  if (num === 0) {
    ...
     var featureCollection = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": _locations // use the new _locations array
      };

    ...
 }
```

});

Comment: for your reference , mongoose document.js
/**
 * Helper for console.log
 *
 * @api public
 */

Document.prototype.inspect = function (options) {
  var opts = options && 'Object' == options.constructor.name
    ? options
    : undefined
  return inspect(this.toObject(opts));
};

Comment: Wow. That's very nontrivial (at least to me). I really, really appreciate your insight. I just edited my route, and now it works. I'm still slightly confused as to what the issue is. How would the inspect defined on Document interfere with the res.json operation?

Comment: I just added another answer to explain how inspect on document interferes with res.json.

Answer (score 0):

When res.json(obj) is called, the first thing this method does is to call JSON.stringify(obj);

If the obj has toJSON defined , the object returned from invoking obj.toJSON() is used by the JSON.stringify.

If you provide a toJSON method on an object and if it is coded to return another object
and not the object on which toJSON is defined, JSON.stringify will operate on this new object.
And you will be able to view the properties of this new object and not the actual object.

res.json relies on toJSON.

console.log relies on inspect.

I just demonstrated the above with this code snippet,

```
var util = require('util');

function Document(){this._doc = {};}

Document.prototype.inspect = function(){return util.inspect(this._doc)};
Document.prototype.toJSON = function(){return this.inspect()};

var docInst = new Document();

docInst.newProp = 'abc'; //property never shows up in console.log / JSON.stringify

docInst._doc._newProp = "_abc";

console.log(docInst);
JSON.stringify(docInst);
```